# To find Maximum Average Subarray

Tags: java, arrays, average, sliding-window

This is a Leetcode problem,
You are given an integer array nums consisting of n elements, and an integer k. Find a contiguous subarray whose length is equal to k that has the maximum average value and return this value. Any answer with a calculation error less than 10-5 will be accepted.

Example 1:

Input: nums = [1,12,-5,-6,50,3], k = 4
Output: 12.75000
Explanation: Maximum average is (12 - 5 - 6 + 50) / 4 = 51 / 4 = 12.75

I feel like I'm close, but there's some small logical error that I'm unable to figure out. Please help me out. This is the code I wrote so far:

```
class Solution {
    public double findMaxAverage(int[] nums, int k) {
        int n = nums.length;
        int sum=0;
        double avg;
        double maxavg=0.0;
        for(int i=0;i<n-k+1;i++)
        {
            for(int j=0;j<k;j++)
            {
                sum = sum+nums[i+j];
            }
            avg=((double)sum/(double)k);
            maxavg = Math.max(avg,maxavg);
        }
        return maxavg;
    }
}
```

Comment: the mistake is: you are always "increasing" sum, however you should reset it at each iteration of outer loop. moreover, I do believe the idea of "sliding window" is to reuse previous computations - there should be just one loop.

Comment: You really just need to maximize the sum. Do the division once at the end and work with integers within the loop.

Comment: For reference, the LeetCode page for this problem is https://leetcode.com/problems/maximum-average-subarray-i/

Comment: Please edit the question, and explain why you believe your code has a problem. It would help to include example input (in this case, values of `nums` and `k`), expected output, and actual output.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need a double loop for this. Just iterate over the numbers array, removing the number from one end and adding the number at the other end.

```
int sum = 0;
int max = 0;
for (int i = 0; i < k; i++) {
  sum = sum + nums[i];
}
max = sum;
for (int i = k; i < nums.length; i++) {
  sum = sum - nums[i - k] + nums[i];
  max = Math.max(sum, max);
}
double avg = max / (double) k;
```